# GIS confidentiality, how to convert address to block level

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geocoding

I have a list of addresses in a spreadsheet to use with ArcGIS and geocode using the provided ESRI street level geolocator.

But I intend to make point information viewable for the public, thus I want to change sensitive address information to the block level.
EG: 2686 Workman Street, Los Angeles CA 90031 -> 
recoded to the block level as 2600-2700 Workman Street, Los Angeles, CA 90031

What can I do to accomplish this other than manually rewriting hundreds of entries?

Comment: Why is a street address sensitive information? It's not Personally Identifiable Information.  It's quite definitely public data.  I can walk down the street and make a list of the house numbers without any consequence.  If I want to do it even faster, I can easily purchase a saturation mailing list from the white pages.  I guess the question is, why try to obscure?  Unless you are associating something specific with the address - something that maybe doesn't need to be known by everyone.  The US Census bureau aggregates to the block level for just such a reason. They use tracts and blocks.

Comment: The nature of the data contains sensitive information that isn't available to public channels, which is the main reason why I'd need to anonymize it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert all the addresses to latitude and longitude then delete the addresses. Then spatial join to the vector street line closest. Then delete the coordinates. Then the file will have just the block info.

Comment: This worked perfect and it was very simple, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Good question.  I don't know where you can find out the range for each block but maybe this will help you get started.  Using the ZIP+4 data from the USPS or a distributor like [zip-codes.com](http://www.zip-codes.com/zip-plus-4-database.asp) (I have no affiliation) you can determine the valid ranges for each street.  for example, 0-10 odd or 13-29 even.  Again, you'll still need to be able to determine the blocks.

Comment: Can I do this from the address locator service? I can do a spatial join with census blocks, but it is not specific enough to show the desired information

Comment: Which address locator service are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Census Block GIS data are part of a larger dataset called TIGER, for Topologically Integrated Geographic Encoding and Referencing. Block boundaries are defined based on the location of roads and other lines in the "All Lines" TIGER dataset (also known as "Edges"). The lines in the Edges dataset include address ranges for both left and right sides of the road, as shown on [page 2 of the documentation](http://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/pdfs/tiger/tgrshp2010/TGRSHP10SF1AA.pdf).

I would perform a [spatial join](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000q000000) of address points to Edges lines and then create a new composite address based on the `FULLNAME`, `LFROMADD`, `LTOADD`, `RFROMADD`, and `RTOADD` fields in combined attribute table.

Answer (score 0):

I would not rely on the highest rated answer in this case.  Simply moving points to the closest line will result in addresses being placed on the wrong lines.  If you are doing this from a public safety perspective, and have a mall (for example) where your addresses are based off a main road 500 feet north of where they are recorded, and you have a residential location south of the mall with the street centerline being 400 feet south of the addresses on the property, all the mall incidents will be placed on the wrong street indicating incidents occur on that street heavily.  My research as lead me to converting all addresses to hundred block addresses, then utilizing a geocoder to geocode to the street centerline.  The geocoder can plot '2500 Block of N Main St'.